# Iterating through XML document with XPath without printing duplicates

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath, xsd

I have this XML document:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tns:request xmlns:tns="urn">
    <tns:CorrectingData>
        <tns:CorrectingDataBlock>
            <tns:CurrentVersionData>current</tns:CurrentVersionData>
            <tns:NewVersionData>new</tns:NewVersionData>
        </tns:CorrectingDataBlock>
        <tns:CorrectingDataBlock>
            <tns:CurrentVersionData>100</tns:CurrentVersionData>
            <tns:NewVersionData>200</tns:NewVersionData>
        </tns:CorrectingDataBlock>
    </tns:CorrectingData>
</tns:request>
```

And corresponding XSD document:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xsd:element name="request" type="tns:requestType">
</xsd:element>

<xsd:complexType name="requestType">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="CorrectingData" type="tns:CorrectingDataType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="CorrectingDataType">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="CorrectingDataBlock" type="tns:CorrectingDataTextType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="CorrectingDataTextType">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="CurrentVersionData" type="tns:string">
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="NewVersionData" type="tns:string">
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

</xsd:schema>
```

**I need to display the entire XSD document on edit form and, where possible, insert data from the XML document.** In my example, I've simplified the code so that it will output the values of the leaf items to the console.

To insert data from XML document I want to iterate through each `tns:CorrectingDataBlock` element and print values of its leafs (`tns:CurrentVersionData` and `tns:NewVersionData`). **I need output to be like this:**

```
current
new
100
200
```

I have this javascript code, which goes through XSD document and creates XPath, so I can use it to find and print values of leafs from XML document.

```js
// ...
// dataXPath = `/*[local-name()='${childElement.getAttribute("name")}']`
// I'm using recursive method, which fills dataXPath from root and passes it to child node all the way to the leaf.
// After I reach the leaf node I print its value.

const childElementDataXPath: string = dataXPath + `/*[local-name()='${childElement.getAttribute("name")}']`;
const snapshotXPathResult: XPathResult = this._dataDocument.evaluate(childElementDataXPath, this._dataDocument, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);

for (let i: number = 0; i < snapshotXPathResult.snapshotLength; i++) {
  const node: Element = snapshotXPathResult.snapshotItem(i) as Element;
  console.log(node.textContent);
}
// ...
```

The result XPath which this code is creating is:

```xml
/*[local-name()='request']/*[local-name()='CorrectingData']/*[local-name()='CorrectingDataBlock']/*[local-name()='CurrentVersionData']
```

and

```xml
/*[local-name()='request']/*[local-name()='CorrectingData']/*[local-name()='CorrectingDataBlock']/*[local-name()='NewVersionData']
```

And code generates this output:

```
current
100
new
200
current
100
new
200
```

**Question:** How do I change my code to get that I want? What I'm doing wrong?

**Notes:**

- I ought to use `local-name()` function in XPath because I don't know namespace of XML document at the execution time.

**Full code listing:**

```js
export class Parser {

    public _schemeDocument: Document;
    public _dataDocument: Document;

    public processElement(element: Element, dataXPath: string): void {
        const typeName: string = this._getElementTypeName(element);
        const typeElement: Element = this._getTypeElementByName(typeName);

        dataXPath += `/*[local-name()='${element.getAttribute("name")}']`;

        if (typeElement && this._isComplexType(typeElement)) {
            const sequence = this._schemeDocument.evaluate("./*[local-name()='sequence']", typeElement).iterateNext();
            if (sequence) {
                Array.prototype.forEach.call((sequence as Element).children, (childElement: Element) => {
                    if (this._isElement(childElement)) {
                        const childElementDataXPath: string = dataXPath + `/*[local-name()='${childElement.getAttribute("name")}']`;
                        const snapshotXPathResult: XPathResult = this._dataDocument.evaluate(childElementDataXPath, this._dataDocument, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);

                        const childTypeName: string = this._getElementTypeName(childElement);
                        const childTypeElement: Element = this._getTypeElementByName(childTypeName);
                        if (childTypeElement && this._isComplexType(childTypeElement)) {
                            for (let i: number = 0; i < snapshotXPathResult.snapshotLength; i++) {
                                this.processElement(childElement, dataXPath);
                            }
                        } else {
                            const childElementCaption: string = this._getElementCaption(childElement);

                            for (let i: number = 0; i < snapshotXPathResult.snapshotLength; i++) {
                                const node: Element = snapshotXPathResult.snapshotItem(i) as Element;
                                const childElementValue: string = node ? node.textContent : "EMPTY";
                                console.log(childElementCaption + ": " + childElementValue);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    private _getElementTypeName(element: Element): string {
        const splittedTypeName: string[] = element.getAttribute("type").split(":");
        return splittedTypeName.length > 1 ? splittedTypeName[1] : splittedTypeName[0];
    }

    private _getTypeElementByName(typeName: string): Element {
        const simpleTypeXPath = `//*[local-name()='simpleType'][@name='${typeName}']`;
        const complexTypeXPath = `//*[local-name()='complexType'][@name='${typeName}']`;
        return this._schemeDocument.evaluate(`${simpleTypeXPath}|${complexTypeXPath}`, this._schemeDocument).iterateNext() as Element;
    }

    private _getElementCaption(element: Element): string {
        const elementCaption: Node = this._schemeDocument.evaluate(".//*[local-name()='documentation']", element).iterateNext();
        return elementCaption ? elementCaption.textContent : "EMPTY";
    }

    private _isComplexType(element: Element): boolean {
        return element.localName === "complexType";
    }

    private _isElement(element: Element): boolean {
        return element.localName === "element";
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have `_dataDocument`, why can't you read out `_dataDocument.documentElement.namespaceURI`, to get the namespace of the root element?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! You're right, I may use that in my code. But even if I do so, I don't know how it will help me to solve my main problem with duplicates in output.

Comment: XPath from changed code is looking like this: `/tns:request/tns:CorrectingData/tns:CorrectingDataBlock/tns:CurrentVersionData`. It's still has the same flaw with duplicates in output. @MartinHonnen

Comment: It is hard to tell from that snippet, if you write recursive code make sure you don't process everything from the root downwards in your recursion, instead, make sure you process child nodes relative to each for their parent nodes.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Great advice! I am trying to apply your code on my system. I'll write as soon as I get some results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my `processElement()` method to this:

```js
public processElement(element: Element, dataXPath: string, numberOfDataElementsOfSameType: number = 1, elementDataIndex: number = 0): void {
    const typeName: string = this._getElementTypeName(element);
    const typeElement: Element = this._getTypeElementByName(typeName);

    if (numberOfDataElementsOfSameType > 1) {
        dataXPath += `/*[local-name()='${element.getAttribute("name")}'][${elementDataIndex + 1}]`;
    } else {
        dataXPath += `/*[local-name()='${element.getAttribute("name")}']`;
    }

    if (typeElement && this._isComplexType(typeElement)) {
        const sequenceElement: Element = this._schemeDocument.evaluate("./*[local-name()='sequence']", typeElement).iterateNext() as Element;
        if (sequenceElement) {
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(sequenceElement.children, (childElement: Element) => {
                const childDataXPath: string = dataXPath + `/*[local-name()='${childElement.getAttribute("name")}']`;
                const childResult: XPathResult = this._dataDocument.evaluate(childDataXPath, this._dataDocument, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
                const childTypeName: string = this._getElementTypeName(childElement);
                const childTypeElement: Element = this._getTypeElementByName(childTypeName);
                if (childTypeElement && this._isComplexType(childTypeElement)) {
                    for (let i: number = 0; i < childResult.snapshotLength; i++) {
                        if (childResult.snapshotLength > 1) {
                            this.processElement(childElement, dataXPath, childResult.snapshotLength, i);
                        } else {
                            this.processElement(childElement, dataXPath, 1, 0);
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    const childElementCaption: string = this._getElementCaption(childElement);
                    for (let i: number = 0; i < childResult.snapshotLength; i++) {
                        const childDataElement: Element = childResult.snapshotItem(i) as Element;
                        const childDataElementValue: string = childDataElement ? childDataElement.textContent : "EMPTY";
                        console.log(childElementCaption + ": " + childDataElementValue);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The main change is that the XPath now contains the index of the element from the XML document. This helps to avoid duplicate leaf elements. In an example with multiple `tns:CorrectingDataBlock` elements new XPath looks like this:

```
/*[local-name()='request']/*[local-name()='CorrectingData']/*[local-name()='CorrectingDataBlock'][1]/*[local-name()='CurrentVersionData']
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just simply use DOM methods:

```js
const xmlSource = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tns:request xmlns:tns="urn">
    <tns:CorrectingData>
        <tns:CorrectingDataBlock>
            <tns:CurrentVersionData>current</tns:CurrentVersionData>
            <tns:NewVersionData>new</tns:NewVersionData>
        </tns:CorrectingDataBlock>
        <tns:CorrectingDataBlock>
            <tns:CurrentVersionData>100</tns:CurrentVersionData>
            <tns:NewVersionData>200</tns:NewVersionData>
        </tns:CorrectingDataBlock>
    </tns:CorrectingData>
</tns:request>`;

const xmlDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xmlSource, 'application/xml');

const blockList = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagNameNS('*', 'CorrectingDataBlock');

for (let i = 0; i < blockList.length; i++) {
  Array.from(blockList[i].children).forEach(c => console.log(c.textContent));
}
```

Comment: I cannot use this code because I need to display the entire XSD document and, where possible, insert data from the XML document. Your approach eliminates the possibility of displaying an entire XSD document and focuses on displaying an XML document. I am sorry for the insufficient information. This was the main reason why I recursively collect XPath and then use it to find data in an XML document.